# How to do "keep with next" paragraph?

Tags: r, paragraph, officer

I use the "officer" package in R to create a Word document. 
In this document, I have several pictures with picture titles. But sometimes, the picture title is in a page, and the picture is in the next page. In Word, the function "keep with next" can be used in the "paragraph" menu in order to the title and the picture keep always together.
How to do with the officer package ?

Thanks

Elodie

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example of your current code that you're using?

Comment: you can use fp_par and its new argument `keep_with_next`. Not on cran yet

Comment: Thank you +++ David for this new argument and your package !